# How to pass an array in an argument

Tags: java, arrays

I'm curious if there's any way to hard code a `drawPolygon` in Java. Usually you are supposed to do something like this

```
int[] x = {50,200,10};
int[] y = {20,300,50};
page.drawPolygon(x, y, 3);
```

and I am curious if there is any way to do something similar to this:

```
page.drawPolygon({50,200,10}, {20,300,50}, 3);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but is not as short as you wished:

```
page.drawPolygon(new int[] {50,200,10}, new int[] {20,300,50}, 3);
```

As you already know, the short just-brackets notation for arrays is useful only for declaring attributes and local variables:

```
int[] x = { 50, 200, 10 };
```

It's a shame, a bit of syntactic sugar would have been nice/useful here. Same thing for maps, which should have a literal syntax. Dynamic languages have an advantage in this!